# Build problems with XobotOS

Tags: eclipse, build, mono, sharpen-tool, xobotos

I am trying to build the [XobotOS](https://github.com/xamarin/XobotOS) source code released by Xamarin on Github and I am using the guidelines provided in the README.build document in the root folder. I have been successful in executing all the steps mentioned in the readme but for some reason the second instance of eclipse does not generate anything. I'd appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks.

Here are some other details which might be useful:

OS: Ubuntu 11.04
Eclipse: Eclipse SDK 4.2 (Juno)
Mono: ? (I am not sure I am probably using a hacked up version of it built from source)

In the meanwhile I will try to download OpenSUSE and give this a try again.

Comment: It is very likely that Xamarin uses openSUSE to build XobotOS (consider their relationship with openSUSE in the past), so you might try that first (as you already did attempt) and then update this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.04 includes a very old version of Mono.

I would try using Ubuntu 12.04 (or if that still fails, use direchtex's PPA with Ubuntu 12.04) or, as Lex Li already suggested, try openSUSE 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

I too recently read about the same and after multiple attempts managed to build it half way. Below are the config that I have.

- Ubuntu: 12.04
- Eclipse: 3.7.2
- Mono: 2.10.8.1 (Both eclipse and mono from the Ubuntu repo itself)

Just followed README.build guidelines. Getting the eclipse/sharpen was quite difficult for me as well. With all the settings as mentioned, I was getting an empty output folder. Unchecked the build automatically flag and gave manual build. After that it worked for me. Building the C# code was straight forward. Yet to try building the Skiya and other libraries.

I had to do minor changes in XobotActivityManager.cs file to get it working. Changed the line below

```
if (now >= at) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((state) => control.Invoke (dispatch));
```

to

```
if (now >= at) {
    if(control.IsHandleCreated)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((state) => control.Invoke (dispatch));
```

*UPDATE*  I recently tried eclipse juno and it doesn't work anymore.